# Getting last Workflow status of a web content in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, workflow, liferay-dxp

How can i perform to get Last Workflow status of a web content in liferay ?
In fact, I've tried with  `WorkflowTaskManagerUtil` with calling `getWorkflowTasksByUser` or even with `search` methods but without success.

Answer (score 1):

The web content entity has version and status fields. You can retrieve the latest content using any of the getLatestAeticle methods from the class JournalArticleLocalService and check the status. On class WorkflowConstants you can find all the available status and its values.